# Fixed div height:100% on mobile devices when scrolling doesn't fill screen

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive `nav` element. The `nav` is `position:fixed`. When clicked it has `top:0 bottom:0` (I've also tried height:100%) `left:0 and right:0`. Hence the nav element overlays the entire screen.

However on mobile devices if I scroll down, the browser address bar (Safari and Chrome on my iPhone) gets shorter or disappears all together - making the viewport higher. Yet the height of the nav element stays the same, meaning that it no longer covers the full screen and there is a strip at the bottom showing the content behind.

How do I resolve this? (I've also tried `height:100vh`). I don't want to use JS or JQ.

Thank you

```
nav {
position:fixed;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
background-color:black;
}


<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="workshops.html">Workshops</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Basically the element is not growing in height to respond to the larger viewport height. The elements height is staying the same, dispite the browser address bar disappearing (in Chrome)

Comment: Please provide your full code.

Comment: Did you tried `min-height`

Comment: can u give ur html too?

Comment: min-height doesn't change anything

Comment: Have you tried disabling scrolling on the main content while the menu is shown? (overflow:hidden for the html element)

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting overscroll-behavior to none in the body, more info can be found in this helpful article : 
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/08/scroll-bouncing-websites/

Answer (score 0):

does your html contain view tag?
something like :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

and then `min-height` . Also using an app container div would be a good choice.

Generally if it's mobile then you better have an app-container div like:

```css
html, body {
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#app-container {
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  top:0;   left:0;
  bottom:0; right:0;
}

nav {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;  left:0;
  min-height:100%;
  background:#123;
}
```

```html
<div id="app-container">
  <nav>
    <ul><li>something</li></ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

this can be helpful : http://coderchronicles.org/2016/04/12/create-a-full-screen-layout-for-mobile-web-apps/

Comment: Yes.  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 0):

Fixed position elements are fixed to the viewport. So a fixed element of top and bottom 0 are fixed to the top and bottom of the viewport.

Unfortunately when the viewport on mobile devices changes (when the address bar shrinks) fixed position elements don't respond.

Comment: Did you found a solution?, I think that I have a same problem, but nothing on this in the web so far

Comment: No I haven't found a solution. I've noticed that even well known businesses can have this problem on their websites