# Any issues with position fixed on a child element - when parent has position absolute?

Tags: css

This appears to work, but I'd like to know if there are issues:

The `nav` has position absolute (I want this to overlay the entire page / body). The child `ul` element has position fixed.

Is this okay? Or should I have a seperate "overlay" div and then a fixed nav?

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="workshops.html">Workshops</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

nav {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

nav ul {
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:48px;
    line-height:1.75em;
    }
```

Comment: if the ul is fixed why does the nav have to be absolute, why not just fix the nav?

Comment: See my answer to my own post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51192019/fixed-div-height100-on-mobile-devices-when-scrolling-doesnt-fill-screen?noredirect=1#comment89367107_51192019

Comment: ah right, that's just rubbish iphones!

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I can think of, is the case when you have a structure

`position: relative` -> `position: absolute` -> `position: fixed`

Then the one with `relative` could be moved somehow (other static elements could push it down, or to the side, they could have margins that would reposition it), and then both your elements `absolute` and `fixed` would be repositioned as well.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this answer, could you please tell me what was wrong with it?